# Regex match any word that contains a sequence exactly once

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches any word containing, let's say, the sequence 'ab' exactly once. So it should match these:

- aaaabaaa
- ab
- abomination

and not these:

- something
- abab
- bacba

With my current regex `\w*ab\w*` I get all of the first list but also the second one of the second list as you can see in the snippet below. How can I specify that it should only match if it contains exactly one 'ab'?

```js
let text = "aaaabaaa ab abomination something abab bacba";

console.log(text.match(/\w*ab\w*/ig));
```

I searched for a while and didn't find a solution but if this is a duplicate of some kind please let me know and I will remove the question.

Comment: Use [`\b(?!\w*ab\w*ab)\w*ab\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/eHwDQm/1), or [`\b(?:(?!ab)\w)*ab(?:(?!ab)\w)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eHwDQm/2).

Comment: Thank you, @Wiktor Stribiżew. If you could elaborate on the sub-elements in an answer I could accept it and learn something as well :)

Comment: Just for future reference if you haven't tried it out have a look at https://regexr.com/.... Or as Wiktor mentioned below in his demo https://regex101.com does the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a regex starting with a word boundary (`\b`) and then having a negative lookahead that will avoid matching words having two non-consecutive `ab` letter sequences:

```
\b(?!\w*ab\w*ab)\w*ab\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eHwDQm/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!\w*ab\w*ab)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are two repetitions of 0+ word chars and `ab`
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `ab` - an `ab` substring
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars.

Note that in some cases you would need to only match letters, and then it will make sense to change `\w` (it matches letters, digits and underscores, and may match more than that if it is Unicode aware) to `[^\W\d_]`, `[[:alpha:]]`,  `[a-zA-Z]`, `\p{L}`, etc. depending on what you need and the regex engine.